# icefaces 1.8.2 Datapaginator unexpected PaneltabSet content swap

Tags: icefaces

I have a web application with multiple tabs. All tabs have managed beans in session scope. The managed beans contains a DataPaginator member, it has a getter and setter method. I set ice:dataPaginator component "binding" options to this paginator in the xhtml page. I would like to use as if I add a new element to the datatable and the table has more rows than table max rows in this situation the pager will go to the next page to see the new element. This works fine, but if I reload the full page (F5) then the page swap panelTabs' contents. I searched a lot but I couldn't get any solution. Thanks for any help or suggestion.

mlal